# Changing value of array elements

Tags: arrays, c

The function below searches for the elements in the array `h` that match the input value. It then shows the index and the value of the matching elements.

```
void search()
{
    int key, index, i, flag = 0, hkey;

    printf("\nenter search element\n");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    hkey = key % TABLE_SIZE;
    for(i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        index = (hkey + i * i) % TABLE_SIZE;
        if(h[index] == key)
        {
            printf("\n value is found at index %d \t value =  %d", index, key);
            key == 99999999;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it change the value of the matching elements in the array?

Comment: Just assign something to `h[index]`

Comment: `key==99999999` doesn't do anything. `==` is a comparison, but you're not using the result of this comparison for anything.

Comment: If you want to get out of the loop when you find the matching term, use `break`

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` to exit a loop. Do not do it by arbitrarily changing a variable to make the loop test condition false. (There are situations where changing a variable naturally results in terminating the loop, but doing so by setting the key to `99999999` is an ugly kludge, is unnecessary because that is what `break` is for, and makes the code more of a nuisance to read.)

`key==99999999;` compares `key` to `99999999` and then does nothing with the result. To assign a value, use `=`, not `==`.

To assign a value to an array element, use `h[index] = value;`.